# Accessing Google Drive Files On The Server Side Of A Website

Tags: javascript, php, html, google-apps-script, server-side-scripting

So I'm making a website. I need to submit a form to a server to be processed. This is required to process login information. This server-side script needs to access a plain-text file which is stored on my Google Drive in order to confirm that the user input is valid. The only way that I know how to access a file on Google Drive is through Google Apps Script.

**Is there a way to handle forms on the server-side that are submitted from another website with HTML or JavaScript in Google Apps Script?** or **Is there a way to use PHP with Google Apps Script?** or **Is there another more efficient way that I can access and write to files on my Google Drive directly from my website?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make an HTTP request to an Apps Script and get a response back.  Take a look at the [Content Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/content).  Google also has a PHP Client API that you can use.  You would need to use the [Drive Service](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/quickstart-php).

Comment: This looks like it's what I'm looking for. But how do I retrieve and access the form data that I send to my Google Apps Script? Also, how would I use this to link to another page if the user input is valid?

Comment: You'll need to do some research on those subjects.  No one can answer those questions in the space of a comment field.  If you want to, take a look at my profile, and send me an email.  I can give you some links to resources.